# How to use Alamofire 3.0 .responsePropertyList in Swift 2.0?

Tags: xml, swift, alamofire

I am trying to read a plist from the web using Alamofire.

My code is as follow:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, encoding: .PropertyList(.XMLFormat_v1_0, 0))
.responsePropertyList { request, response, array, error in

// 2
if let error = error {
  print("Error: \(error)")

// 3
} else if let array = array as? [[String: String]] {

  // 4
  if array.isEmpty {
    print("No flavors were found!")

  // 5
  } else {
    self.flavors = self.flavorFactory.flavorsFromDictionaryArray(array)
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    self.selectFirstFlavor()
  }
}
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

Tuple types '(NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, Result)' (aka '(Optional, Optional, Result)') and '(_, _, _, _)' have a different number of elements (3 vs. 4)

the Last version of Alamofire specify to use
  `responsePropertyList(options: NSPropertyListReadOptions)`
NSPropertyListReadOptions is an emun with 3 values. I don't how to confirm to it if I want to check for possible error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the 3.0.0-beta.3 [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/3.0.0-beta.3#response-handling) and the [Alamofire 3.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md). We put them together to help with questions like these. We ALWAYS want to make MAJOR version bumps as seamless as possible for the community.

Comment: Man I scratched my head on this for almost an entire day :-/  and the answer was right there in front of me. Maybe a link to a tutorial highlighting key changes to a new version could help in the future. But thanks for the awesome framework :-D

Comment: You bet dude! We have the link the migration guides fairly high up in the README. If you have any ideas on how to help out with discoverability beyond that, we're certainly all ears!

Comment: Maybe in the Usage section of the README file you could add what version of Alamofire that usage correspond to. Something like Usage for Alamofire 2.x. It is a small mention, but I believe it could  make a difference.